# Jenkins GitHub Pull Request Builder is being triggered by comments that don't match trigger phrase

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github-api

I have a repo that has three distinct "apps". Each app has a build job on Jenkins, they can all be triggered by a separate trigger phrase on a GitHub PR:
`jenkins build app1`
`jenkins build app2`
`jenkins build app3`

Also, I have configured the trigger phrase on the job only (The "test phrase" field is blank in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > GHPRB > Advanced).

The problem that I'm having is that *any* comment on a PR will trigger *all three* of these builds. Does anybody know how to fix this? I've exhausted my resources and have no idea where to look next.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, so maybe this will not solve yours.
In fact the trigger phrase IS a regexp.

Try `.*jenkins build app1.*` etc.

Be sure of the following:

- set `refspec` to `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
- set `Branch Specifier` to `${sha1}`